# Getting IE to render doc ready function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble getting all versions internet explorer to render my jQuery code. It work wonderful in FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera. The code is at the bottom of the html file right before the  tag. I've also tried the code on the top before the  tag without any luck. I'm not sure if this is the proper way to set up set positions and sizes on a scalable website, but the code is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    resizeDiv();
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
    resizeDiv();
}

function resizeDiv() {
    mainheight = $(window).width() * .7275;

    //Adjusting height
    $('#main').css({'height': mainheight + 'px'});
    $('#content').css("height", $('#content').width() / 3.9608 + "px");

    //Adjusting width
    $('#aacsbbottomimage').css("width", $(window).width() / 9.9365 + "px");
    $('#checkimg1').css("width", $(window).width() / 12.52 + "px");
    $('#checkimg2').css("width", $(window).width() / 12.52 + "px");
    $('#checkimg3').css("width", $(window).width() / 12.52 + "px");

    //Adjusting top positions
    $('#content').css('top', mainheight * .485 + 'px');
    $('#header').css('top', mainheight * .05 + 'px');
    $('#contentheading').css('top', mainheight * .43 + 'px');
    $('#footer').css('top', mainheight * .9 + 'px');

    //Adjusting font sizes
    $('#whiteheader').css("font-size", mainheight / 16.2396 + "px");
    $('#blueheader').css("font-size", mainheight / 16.2396 + "px");
    $('#headerparagraph').css("font-size", mainheight / 56.25 + "px");
    $('#contentheading').css("font-size", mainheight / 47.3684 + "px");
    $('#submitbutton').css("font-size", mainheight / 69.2307 + "px");
    $('#one').css("font-size", mainheight / 55 + "px");
    $('#two').css("font-size", mainheight / 55 + "px");
    $('#three').css("font-size", mainheight / 55 + "px");
    $('#formtext').css("font-size", mainheight / 57 + "px");
    $('#footer').css("font-size", mainheight / 75 + "px");
    $('#section1').css("font-size", $(window).width() / 130.5 + "px");
    $('#section2').css("font-size", $(window).width() / 145.5 + "px");
}
```

Comment: What versions of IE doesn't it work in?

Comment: Can you setup a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: All versions I'm assuming. Getting the same results in ie7 and 1e9. I'll set up a fiddle.

Comment: Heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wD228/

I realize that I still have to change some of the stuff with the background in order to get that to display properly in IE, but everything is set to displayed according to the "main" div, and IE doesn't render is even close.

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle seems ok here in IE10, and maybe better than in Opera 12.15 though I don't really know what to look for.

The main difference between the fiddle and the code you describe is where the script is positioned within the document.

Try moving it into the document's `<head>...</head>` and phrase as follows :

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

That will give it a fighting chance.